# Hydrological conditioning using stream vector in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, vector, dem, elevation, hydrology

I would like to make an hydrological conditioning of a DEM using an available stream network in vector form. I know *r.hydrodem* but it doesn't allow to use the stream vector. I need something to burn the stream network in the DEM to assure water flowing.

Is there a solution in GRASS?

Answer (score 3):

Please check [r.carve](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.carve.html) which generates stream channels by taking a vector stream map, transforms it to raster model and subtracts depth from a DEM writing out a new, modified DEM.